# ggplot plotting all data as a single column when barplot plots everything correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My data is a single column like this:

```
Number Assigned Row 
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        1
5        2
6        3
...      ...
```

When I plot using barplot I get what I want:

[image: barplot]

However when I use ggplot + geom_bar I get this:

[image: ggplot + geom_bar]

This is my code for ggplot:

```
  count <- data.frame(alldata[[xaxis]])
  ggplot(data=count, aes(x="My X Axis", y="My Y Axis")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

versus the code I use for barplot:

```
  counts <- table(alldata[[xaxis]])
  barplot(counts,
          main = xaxis,
          xlab = "Percentile",
          cex.names = 0.8,
          col=c("darkblue","red"), beside = group != "NA")
```

Comment: remove the comments around your x and y variables. make sure the x and y variables entered match columns in your dataframe

Comment: @RAB what do you mean by "remove the comments"?

Comment: you dont need th `"` around your x and y variable names. I meant quotes - my bad

Comment: Isn't aes(x, y) just the labels for the plot? How would I plot vs the count then? Since Y should be the count of cases.

Comment: nope, thats xlab and ylab. aes(x ,y) are the names of the variables you would like to show on the x and y column

Comment: OK I changed stat="count" and removed the y aes but now it still hasn't fixed everything. when I do aes(x = AssignedRow), it just counts all records instead of counting records based on the value.

Comment: in the first graph, what is the difference between all of the bars in each of the sections (1-3)? do you have various categories within your data you want to split it over?

Comment: Sorry, I replaced it. This is what it should look like (eventually I would also like to do grouped bar plots but that's another subject.)

Comment: so do you want the height of each bar to represent the count of each assigned option? (1, 2 or 3 I believe)? Or should it be counting something else? Can you post the image you are actually getting?

Comment: @RAB yes I want the count of each assigned option. The image I want is the first one in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(AssRow = sample(1:3, 100, T, c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3)))
head(df)
#   AssRow
#1      2
#2      1
#3      2
#4      3
#5      2
#6      2
```

This will get you a bar chart of the count of each Assigned Row, and colour them:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AssRow, fill=as.factor(AssRow))) + 
  geom_bar()
```

To change the labels use `xlab` `ylab`/make the background prettier:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AssRow, fill=as.factor(AssRow))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("My X-label") +
  ylab("My Y label") +
  theme_bw()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That fixed it. I was just missing the AssRow  = sample(...) in my data.frame function.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: no what what I do, I can't seem to be able to re-label the fill (as.factor(AssRow))

Comment: Add `+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))` to the end